# Efficient way to list and count distinct specific words

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, distributed-computing

From a plain [text file](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt) I want to count and list distinct words which:

- start with `p` (A)
- end with `p` (B)
- start and end with `p` (A ∩ B)

As a result the cardinality of A, B, A ∩ B and a list of all items within A ∩ B is required.

Here is my solution; please note that I do not distinguish between upper and lower case, also the parsing is extremely simple for illustration:

```
val source = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt"

def p(w:String) : Int = {
    (if (w.charAt(0) == 'p') 1 else 0) +
        (if (w.charAt(w.length - 1) == 'p') 2 else 0)
}

sc.addFile(source)

val r = sc.textFile(
    org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get(source.split("/").last)
).flatMap(
    line => line.split("[\\s]").map(
         word => word.toLowerCase()
            .replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}']", "")
    ).filter(w => !w.isEmpty && p(w) > 0)
).distinct().flatMap(w => {
    val k = p(w)

    if (k == 3) {
        Seq((1, w), (2, w), (3, w))
    } else {
        Seq((k, w))
    }
})

r.countByKey().foreach(println)
r.filter(t => t._1 == 3).map(t => t._2).foreach(println)
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I think I'm using here one wide transformation (`distinct`) and one action (`countByKey`). Thus I should have three stages in the linage for the cardinality and two for the items of the intersection of A and B:

[image: Lineage for the cardinality]
[image: Lineage for the items of the intersection]

Let's say I would process here a really huge set of files (with `parallelize` at the beginning). Is the given approach suitable? If not how could I improve it? E.g. calling `p(w)` only once in the lineage, reducing the stages, iterations etc.

Comment: The second `flatMap` is, to my mind, unnecessary. You could do that same processing when you flat map the lines of the file.

`countByKey` does not actually require a shuffle.

My gut says you may be prematurely optimizing.

Comment: I had a version before this, without the second `flatMap` but then I was starting doing some stuff to flip the key value because I don't know an alternative to `countByKey` for a value. So I thought either I could group by value for `(partition, word)` or I could count by value for `(word, partition)` or any other approach I'm currently not seeing to remove the second `flatMap`. Regarding the optimization, this question is currently more some kind of training to get more familiar with spark ^^. Thanks for your hint regarding `countByKey`, I'll update my question!

Comment: @hoyland It seems that `countByKey` is an operation (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#CountByLink) which returns a `HashMap`. So currently I would say this does require a shuffle. What do you think? And would be a `reduceByKey` the better choice because it delivers another `RDD` instead of a `HashMap`?

Comment: Inspired by this article and code, I tried to run it on my machine with a book-size text, 416 lines, 70581 words, 501661 bytes/chars. But I don't know what sc is and used Source.fromFile instead. From there, a little cascade of modifications was necessary and produced aioor-ex. So I wrote my own method, working with a regex. Runs in 2.2s on a 2x2core 5y'o laptop with an old SSD, no performance tuning made, distinct just called at the end and without 'toLowerCase'. Just scala-2.11 with one import: scala.io._. If you're interested, I can post the code in an answer. Results are (P|p)-(p)-Rest.

Comment: It doesn't need to shuffle because you don't need to arrange the data by key first--you can count by key on each executor and then aggregate the counts. (The last sentence of the "Background" section of the docs mentions this, albeit somewhat obliquely.) `countByKey` is what you want here--if you use `reduceByKey` you're going to shuffle (the other `byKey`s do shuffle) and then just collect the `RDD` anyway to obtain the same result. It'd be the right choice if the number of keys was very large or you needed the result as an RDD.

Comment: @hoyland Ah, you are right! Count is a distributive aggregate in general, I forgot about it. Do you have any hint how to dismiss the second `flatMap`?

Comment: @userunknown Yes please! The object `sc` is the Scala context from the shell. Don't forget about the list of all words which are in A and B beside the cardinalities. Best would be if you could also provide some background information about complexity (Big-O) and the aspect of distribution; using terms of Spark. I would say the absolute time seems to be subtle since it will be vary a lot depending on the available hardware and input.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I made a variation from the code, which uses pattern matching, to find words, starting with or ending with 'p', or both.

```
import scala.io._

object Pworp {
    val r = (Source.fromFile ("./dialektik-der-aufklaerung.txt").getLines.filter (_.size > 1).flatMap (
          line => line.split ("""[\]\[ ,.?!»«0-9-]""").filter (_.size > 2).map (_.replaceAll ("^(P|p)?(.*)(p)?$", "$1-$3:$1$2$3")))).toList.groupBy (s => (s(0),s(1))).toList

    ((0 to r.size-1).map (i => r(i)._1 match {
            case (('P'|'p'), 'p') => Some (r(i)._2.distinct)
            case (('P'|'p'), '-') => Some (r(i)._2.distinct)
            case (   '-'   , 'p') => Some (r(i)._2.distinct)
            case (   '-'   , ':') => None // Some (r(i)._2.distinct) -- too many
            case _  => None // Shouldn't happen, but happens, if the 
                            // split-expression is bogus
        })).flatten.map (ri => println (s"${ri.distinct.size}: ${ri.distinct}\n"))

    def main (args: Array[String]) {
        val ex = Pworp
    }
}
```

The result contains no word of the form P....p or p....p, not even one ending with ...p. Now, writing about it, I found it a bit suspicious and made a test with grep, and here I find "Kyklop" and even "Prinzip". So there must be a bug somewhere. Maybe somebody sees it.
It's a German text, so a different distribution P-words than in the Shakespeare wouldn't be unusual.

I end up with 283 P-words:

```
283: List(P-:Philosophical, P-:Programm, P-:Philosophie, P-:Prahlerei, P-:Praxis, P-:Prinzips, P-:Persephone, P-:Prinzipien, P-:Platons ...
```

and 245 p-Words:

```
245: List(p-:planlose, p-:patriarchal:, p-:plausiblen, p-:philosophische, p-:patriarchalen, p-:philosophischen, p-:platonischen, ...
```

Time to run, about 2s on a 2x2-Core Laptop with about 5y'o SSD, to compare the speed.

Big-O-Notation of the algorithm doesn't fall into my field of expertise, and it would need to investigate the different library methods, especially 'replaceAll' to give a result, so maybe it is more practical to test it on your own data and compare the bare results.

I guess, for masses of textes, they should be well be parallelizable on a by-book basis, and each text pretty independent from the other, so if you measure with a typical input size, I guess it will be linear scalable to the number of texts if they are of homogene size.

Timing:

```
scalac shakesp.scala && /usr/bin/time scala -cp .:$CLASSPATH Pworp
2.10user 0.24system 0:01.13elapsed 207%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 92288maxresident)k
24inputs+64outputs (0major+18144minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

The input data is 416 lines, 70581 words, 501661 bytes/chars, counted with `wc` so it differs from the way, lines are split, mainly in punctuation.

Comment: Thanks! Could you share a link of the text corpus?

Comment: Oh, I currently realize, that you did not use Apache Spark! This is an essential part of my question. Check the tags ;)